# Large objects lead to bloated rails - how can I eliminate them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some code that both loads largish objects (1-10 mb, let's say) and then sends them out to the browser.  Naturally, it can also receive them from users and write them to disk.

I understand that that's going to take up some memory but the problem is that it keeps that memory around, and I am getting processes ballooning to something like a gig, which is absurd.

```
 xxxx    3449  3.0 29.9 639156 620304 ?       R    20:22   0:23 Rack: /var/www/xxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx
```

This one has only been around for a few minutes! Ouch!

Any ideas how to keep the size down?  This is Rails 3, and the latest passenger.  ActiveRecord is used for DB access.

Is there a way I can make Rails free up that space after each request?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what these objects are. As arnep points out, if they are supposed to be files then you should be using the xsendfile module for Apache to send them.

Comment: I suppose I could rework things to make them be files - but I would prefer not to.

Comment: They are regular old AR objects with huge strings.  I'm curious if there's a way to ensure they and their memory are freed after each request.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of objects are this?

If it are files from harddisk and you are running Apache you can use [mod_xsendfile for Apache2/Apache2.2](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) to avoid your program to touch these files at all.

Comment: They're loaded from, and saved to the database at the moment.